# New content doesn't appear in database

Tags: 7, nodes

I have the strangest thing going on here: I just created a new content type ('jobs'), and a new job (its node ID is 1706), but for some reasons there is no node that node ID in the database; even when I search for `type = jobs`, I get no result.

What could be the cause why I'm getting no results?

Answer (score 4):

If the content was created it's also there in the database. Most obvious reason for you not finding it, would be silly mistakes, like a typo in the search, or you looked in the wrong database (either created the node the wrong place or looking in the wrong database).

It's not possible to have a node in a drupal site that doesn't exist in the database unless you believe in fairies ;)

Comment: also +1 for fairies :) (who cares if it's the right anwser ;-))

Comment: Haha :-) Although I like fairies, it's not of the mentioned options. I'm sure it's the correct database, I'm sure the content appears in the website and I'm sure the node isn't listed in the database... I'm using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: So you've probably hit a breach in the space/time continuum, because what googletorp said is an apodictic certainty : creating a node in Drupal is creating it in the database. That said, the mistake may not be so obvious : doesn't your software cache things locally or something like this ?